# Try - Except - handling inside a function and separate file possible?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I got this piece of code that is catching an error. Is it possible to write the error handling inside a function for example and then just reference to it inside the code? The goal would be to have all the error handling in a separate file and just call the class inside the code when needed.

This is the normal way and its working fine

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
def main():
    try: 
        x = int("foo")
    except ValueError:
        print("I cought a ValueError")

if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

I would like to try something like this, but is something like this possible? and how is it done in a proper way?:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3


#All the error handeling goes here:

def exceptValueError():
    except ValueError:
        print("I cought a ValueError")

def exceptZeroDivisionError():
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        print("You cant devide by zero")


#Code goes here

def main():
    try: 
        x = int("foo")
    exeptValueError()

if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

This gives me:

```
    except ValueError:
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Is it possible to use try and instead of except use a function that contains an except? I assume that is not really possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def exeptValueError():
    except ValueError:
        print("I cought a ValueError")
```

This won't work because there is no try block before the except block (the try block in main doesn't count).

You could do the following, which would still be close to what you want

```
def exceptValueError():
    print("I caught a ValueError")

def main():
    try: 
        x = int("foo")
    except ValueError:
        exceptValueError()
```

Comment: This looks ok but I don't get any output at all.

Comment: @Barry
It works on my end so I'm not sure what to tell you.
[pic](https://i.imgur.com/fKKGoys.png)

Comment: It works now. I had an issue with indentation. Can anyone say if its ok to do it that way? is it common? what if you want to store all the errors in one file and you don't want to clutter your code with error exceptions. Whats the best practice?